# Can't compile java program with referenced libraries in visual studio code, error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, visual-studio, jar

I have a single file java program for my cs class that requires us to use the stdlib.jar library. I have imported the .jar file and it shows up in the [java project overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfVZ0.png)

[image: java project overview]

as well as in the [settings.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpMti.png).

[image: settings.json file]

The text editor [suggests methods from the library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiebq.png)

[image: suggests methods from the library]

and seems to [know what they do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cfCH.png).

[image: know what they do]

The problem shows up when i try to compile, i use the command line like i usually do, javac project.java, but it just gives me a *error: cannot find symbol* [pointing to StdRandom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XD92.png).

[image: pointing to StdRandom]

I'm at my wits end with this problem and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are not showing *how* you are using the command line to compile, nor what your classpath statement is when you do this. If the jar file is not in the command line classpath (or the jar's manifest's classpath), then this error will occur.

Comment: Thanks i was using javac project name and had tested javac -cp ".jar path" but i used it wrong since i was on windows and i should have been javac -cp ".;../../stdlib.jar" .\project.java and i also had to use those parameters when running